# Can we say that $\emptyset\in\{\emptyset\}$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Is it correct to say that $\emptyset\in\{\emptyset\}$? By definition, the empty set does not contain anything so how can we say that empty belongs to the empty set. And also whether it is right to say that the empty set is contained in empty? I am really confused about this. Please help.

Comment: The thing on the right is not the empty set.  It's the difference between a bag with nothing in it (the empty set) or a bag that contains a bag which is empty ($\{\varnothing\}$).

Comment: **YES**: we have  $a \in \{ a \}$ **always**.

Comment: One of many, many duplicates.

Comment: @AsafKaragila hahah absolutely

Comment: **Hint:** *Every set is a subset of itself.*

Answer (score 3):

"$\{\varnothing\}$" is not "the empty set"; it is "the set containing the empty set".

- $\varnothing$: the empty set
- $\{\}$: the empty set
- $\{\text{Earth}\}$: the set containing "Earth"
- $\{ \varnothing \}$: the set containing the empty set
- $\{ \{\} \}$: the set containing the empty set

Answer (score 2):

$\{\emptyset\}\neq\emptyset$

$\{\emptyset\}$ is a set consisting of one element.  That one element is the empty set.

Comment: @emma it's a hint

Comment: @emma Well...actually this was the question.

Comment: $\{\emptyset\}$ is *a* set consisting of one element.

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It is the only one **element** of the set $\{\emptyset\}$